# Display on a web site if I'm online for Google Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

Currently I can add a "start hangout" button to my web site https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button

However, it's kind of a dead button, it just starts hangouts and there's no way to actually see if I'm online of offline.

Is there a way for me to put next to that button whether or not my Google+ account "...@dancourse.co.uk" is online currently so someone could call me (if they had my address)?

An Api?
A JavaScript library?